# Android Bluetooth low energy advertising fails

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon

I am using the the altbeacon api to transmit beacons intermittently. Over a period of time, the android device advertising the beacon seems to stop transmitting the beacon without any feedback.  The advertisementCallBack returns with a positive response meaning that the device should in fact transmit the beacon.  Ive tried different phones and resetting the application when the problem occurs without any luck.  The only way that I can begin transmitting again is if I manually reset the Bluetooth button in the phone's settings. Why is this happening? Is there a way to detect when it happens? Is there a way to prevent is from happening.

Comment: What device model does this happen with?  You say you tried different phones.  Are they different models or different copies of the same model?

Comment: I am using a moto E (2nd gen) as well as a Samsung S5.

Comment: Is there any reason why the phone would prevent a BLE advertisement.  after 45 minuted to an hour, the phone will just stop sending out advertisements without any indication.  My log shows that the phone is transponding but that is definitely not the case. I must turn the bluetooth hardware switch on and off in order to continue to transmit the advertisements.

Comment: This is certainly not universal behavior.   I have a beacon transmitting for days at a time on Android Things OS on the Raspberry Pi (a fork of Android 7).  I have also done tests for 22 hours+ transmitting on a  Nexus 9 running Android 6.0: http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2015/11/12/battery-friendly-beacon-transmission

Comment: Do you see any system-level log messages when transmitting stops?

Comment: No I do not see any system-level logs.  When I go into the storage settings of the device and select Bluetooth Share, I am able to clear the data, and then I am able to transmit once again.  This causes me to beleive it is some sort of memory leak in my code that is causing the system to prevent transmission.

Comment: Do you get the same results if you turn on the transmitter (then leave it on in the background for 60 minutes) using this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en

Comment: no i dont get the same results

Comment: Meaning, the Locate app keeps transmitting for > 60 minutes?  If so, then, yes, this suggests that the problem is something else inside your app.  You might try making a simpler app until you can isolate the problem, or make it small enough with the problem to post the code in your question.

Comment: @davidgyoung do you have any knowledge of inconsistent functionality with certain devices or android versions.  I am having a problem with a moto E 2nd gen with 4glte running android 5.1 but NOT my Samsung galaxy s5 running android 6.0.1.

Comment: I am certainly aware of lots of bluetooth quirks on various devices, although I have yet to come across an issue with a Moto E 2nd Gen